# Firebase, DataSnapshot cast to Model class

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a problem when I cast `DataSnapshot` to my Model class when using Firebase Database.

I receive the information as DataSnapshot, and when I make it toString() and Log it I see the right information(values) at Database. But when I try to cast it to my Model class I see my default (zero values)

1. **Reference**

   E/Query getRef():       https://********/users/pZl7xHxREefHZu3Zgd7ZZBSJTmA2/activities
2. **DataSnapshot.toString()**

   E/Query DataS:  DataSnapshot { key = activities, value = {29May201720:11:16= {, elapsedTime=0, currentTime=170529201116, (...), 
   myLocationsList={ (...) } //information
   **//last data at current moment**
3. **Model data after cast**

E/Query getVal():  ResourcesFromActivity{averageSpeed=0.0, maxSpeed=0.0, averageStrokeRate=0.0, totalMeters=0} **//zeroed default**

4. **At single Node it's working**

   usersActivitiesRef = database.getReference("message");
   usersActivitiesRef.addValueEventListener(this);

**Code: At onCreate() :**

```
    (mAuth.getCurrentUser() == null) {
        mAuth.getCurrentUser().reload();
    }
    else{
        mUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
        usersActivitiesRef = database.getReference("users").child(mUser.getUid()).child("activities");//.endAt(true).limitToLast(1);

       // usersActivitiesRef = database.getReference("message");
        Query query = usersActivitiesRef.orderByChild("currentTime").limitToLast(1);
        Log.e("Query getRef()",query.getRef().toString());
        //usersActivitiesRef.addValueEventListener(this);
        query.addValueEventListener(this);
    }
```

**On Data Change**

```
@Override
public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot){
    ResourcesFromActivity receivedData = dataSnapshot.getValue(ResourcesFromActivity.class);
    Log.e("Query Ref",dataSnapshot.getRef().toString());
    Log.e("Query DataS","\n "+dataSnapshot.toString() );
    Log.e("Query getVal()","\n "+ receivedData.toString() );
    Log.e("Query","\n "+ Long.toString(receivedData.getTotalMeters()));
    allLocations = receivedData.getMyLocationsList();
  (...)
```

**Model:**

```
@IgnoreExtraProperties
public class ResourcesFromActivity {

public String currentTime;
public long elapsedTime;
public String elapsedTimeStr;
public float averageSpeed;
public float maxSpeed;
public float averageStrokeRate;
public long totalMeters;
public List<MyLocation> myLocationsList = new ArrayList<>();
public List<Location> allLocations = new ArrayList<>();
public List<Float> allStrokes = new ArrayList<>();

public ResourcesFromActivity(){
    // Default constructor required for calls to DataSnapshot.getValue(ResourcesFromActivity.class)
} 
public ResourcesFromActivity(String currentTime, long elapsedTime, String elapsedTimeStr, float averageSpeed, float maxSpeed, float averageStrokeRate, long totalMeters, List<MyLocation> myLocationsList, List<Location> allLocations, List<Float> allStrokes) {
    this.currentTime = currentTime;
    this.elapsedTime = elapsedTime;
    this.elapsedTimeStr = elapsedTimeStr;
    this.averageSpeed = averageSpeed;
    this.maxSpeed = maxSpeed;
    this.averageStrokeRate = averageStrokeRate;
    this.totalMeters = totalMeters;
    this.myLocationsList = myLocationsList;
    this.allLocations = allLocations;
    this.allStrokes = allStrokes;
}
```

**Maybe I did something wrong with indexing**

```
{
  "rules": {
    "users": {
      "$uid": {
        ".read": "true",
        ".write": "$uid === auth.uid",
        "$userId" :{
        "activities":{
         "$activitieId": {
           ".read": "true",
           ".indexOn": ["currentTime"]
         }
        }
      }
      },

}
}
```

}

Thank You

Comment: I can see that your variables are private. Have you created getters and setters for them? Do you have a public constructor taking all the variables as parameters?

Comment: i fixed private variables, but nothing changed,{ i used alt+ Insert and default is private,}

Comment: Create a constructor that takes those variables as parameters. And the public getters and setters.

Comment: Again do not work

Comment: is it possible multiple constructors to make problems?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the problem here is a slight mismatch in what you are getting back as a dataSnapshot vs what you expect to get.

What you are getting back in this case is not a single activity record, it's a Map of activity records, which in this case contains one item(or one child), since that's what you specify in your query.

So this is important as you can't just set this map directly to your `ResourcesFromActivity` class even if the map contains only one item, the fields that are expected don't match up.

One way to do this with your current setup is to modify the `onDataChange` like so:

```
@Override
public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot){
    for(DataSnapshot activitySnapShot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
        ResourcesFromActivity receivedData = activitySnapShot.getValue(ResourcesFromActivity.class);
    }
}
```

Here we are now iterating through the children of the dataSnapshot to get the activity data from the children. In this case it is only one child, but you could modify to deal with multiple children.